# save time stamp in time picker

Tags: android, timepicker

I am developing a android application where I need time stamp should be saved in time picker even if we click back button in android.Since I am new to android I need help.Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you trying to set timestamp value to your TimePicker?

Comment: Yes, set time should not be lost if I click back and again open the same activity.

Comment: You can use the options given elow to store the current timestamp (either in shared preference or sqllite database). Create binding in your activity for timepicker component and set the stored value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Will get you the current timestamp.If you want to save it somehow you may use SharedPrefences or sqlite db or something like this.

I think I would prefer SharedPreferences since you want the timestamp to be there after clicking the back button. Clicking that button might exit you application so some persistent storage would be fine. The timestampt is no POJO so SharePreferences are my first choice.

Something like that should help:

```
// That will save the timestamp
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_TAG_TIMESTAMP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.edit().putLong("PREF_TAG_TIMESTMAP", System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
pref.edit().clear().commit();

// That will get you the timestamp
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_TAG_TIMESTAMP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.getLong("PREF_TAG_TIMESTMAP", -1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to persist you data for a later run of the activity you can do that using the [sql database](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842), [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or if you only need to persist during the current run of the app (not for subsequent launched of the app) you could create a [static variable](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/staticvariable.shtml) holding the values you want to store for you.
From what I understand you should go with the [static variable](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/staticvariable.shtml) approach.

Comment: could you help me what I should do to save the set time even if I click back button .

Comment: To catch the back key i would suggest something like this:
    @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
            if (Integer.parseInt(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) < 5
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                Log.d("CDA", "onKeyDown Called");
                onBackPressed();
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        public void onBackPressed() {
            //save data
            return;
        }`